# Have a duplicate of an object, or how to multiply it

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have a shopping cart with an apple and an orange object. I want to be able to add the apple twice, but I'm not sure how to target the "fruit1" object twice, in order to display 2 apples in the cart. I essentially want to update the cart array with "2 apples", with the price "value" doubled, and 1 orange)

```
module.exports = {
  shoppingCart: function () {
    //create empty cart array
    theCart = [];
    // all fruits
    let fruitProducts = [
      {
        fruit1: 'Apple',
        price: 4.95,
      },
      {
        fruit2: 'Orange',
        price: 3.99,
      },
    ];
    //push the objects into the empty array using the apply method -- add items to the cart
    Array.prototype.push.apply(theCart, fruitProducts);

    //remove items from the cart by calling this function
    function removeAllItems() {
      if ((theCart.length = !0)) {
        theCart = [];
      }
    }
    //removeAllItems();

    console.log(theCart);
  },
};
```

Comment: Recommendation: 1. Add a quantity and subtotal field to each cart entry. 2. Don't use fruit1 and fruit2, just use fruit - or, better yet, item.

Comment: Appreciate the help, John. still working on this but is definitely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map()`. Add property `qty` and `total` and pass a spread of numbers (`...amounts` ex. `1, 2, 5`) representing the quantities of each item.

```js
const fruit = [{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "price": 4.95
  },{
    "fruit": "Orange",
    "price": 3.99
  }
];

const shop = (product, ...amounts) => {
  let qty = [...amounts] || [];
  
  let cart = product.map((item, count) => {
    item.qty = qty[count] || 0;
    item.total = parseFloat((item.qty * item.price).toFixed(2));
    return item;
  });
  return cart;
};
  
console.log(shop(fruit, 1, 3));
console.log(shop(fruit, 4));
console.log(shop(fruit));
console.log(shop(fruit, 1, 3, 2));
```

Comment: Great, glad to help. I updated the answer  and streamlined the checks.

Comment: Thanks, zer00ne once again! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking how to find an object from an array and then copy it.

First, to find fruit1:

```
const apple = fruitProducts.find(fruit => “fruit1” in fruit);
```

Next, to push copies of that object to your cart you can use the spread operator to do a shallow copy:

```
theCart.push(…apple);
theCart.push(…apple);
```

That being said, a better solution is to keep a list of objects whose properties are fruit, quantity, and price. Then you can compute total price once you are done adding items to the cart.